# How do I "copy unless later version exists" in Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, deployment, capistrano

I want to protect my `database.yml` file by keeping it out of version control.  Thus, I have two tasks in my Capistrano deploy recipe:

```
task :copy_db_config do
  # copy local config file if it exists and is more
  # recent than the remote one
end

task :symlink_db_config do
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
end
```

Can you help fill in the first task?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have functioning code for you here and now but..

you can the the local timestamp by using ruby. File class has a function ctime which let's You know when it was changed.

Run the same command on the servers database.yml

If the local one is newest, capistrano has a method for secure upload

`upload("products.txt", "/home/medined", :via => :scp)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I approached it differently. Maybe it will be helpful.

The setup task copies database.yml.example to database.yml. The deploy task does not touch database.yml. I have separate tasks for changing the database names, usernames, and passwords. Here's an example:

```
desc "Change the database name"
task :change_db_database, :roles => :app do
  database = prompt('Enter new database name: ')
  run <<-CMD
    cd #{shared_path}/config &&
    perl -i -pe '$env = $1 if /^(\\w+)/; s/database:.*/database: #{database}/ if $env eq "#{ENV['CONNECTION'] || ENV['TARGET']}"' database.yml
  CMD
end
```

I run these after setup but before the first deploy on new boxes. Then any time after that when I need to change database parameters, I use these tasks instead of copying in a new file.